# C++: When entering numbers into array first number is 0

Tags: c++, calculator, iostream

Trying to make a calculator that calculates values in an array based on input from user. But the first value in the array is always 0 when I leave 'p undefined or p = 1 will have give me the same problem. It should be whatever the user enters for the first value and so on.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main() {

double x;
int p = 1, y = 0;
double sum = 1;
int many[p];
char op;

cout << "How many numbers are you working with today?" << endl;
cin >> x;

do
{
    if (y > x)
    break;

cout << "Enter number " << y + 1 << ":" << endl;
cin >> many[p];

cout << "What would you like the numbers to do: (+ - / *)" << endl;
cin >> op;


if (op == '+')
{
sum+=many[p];
cout << sum <<endl;
}

else if (op == '-')
{
sum-=many[p];
cout << sum <<endl;
}

else if (op == '*')
{
sum*=many[p];
cout << sum <<endl;
}

else if (op == '/')
{
sum/=many[p];
cout << sum <<endl;
}

else {cout << "ERROR: Enter correct value." << endl;}

    y++;

}

    while (y < x);
}
```

The sum should be 3 not 4.

```
How many numbers are you working with today?
2
Enter number 1:
1
What would you like the numbers to do: (+ - / *)
+
Enter number 2:
2
What would you like the numbers to do: (+ - / *)
+
4
```

Comment: Why are you using array in this case? From what I can see from your code is that you are just trying to perform repititive mathematical operations right?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour, because your attempt to read or write `many[p]` is out of bounds. You have declared the array as `int many[p];` so the last member is `many[p-1]`. But, as the @uglyCoder said, why do you even need an array here? Also, variable length arrays (VLAs) are **not** standard C++!!

Comment: The reason that the sum is 4 and not 3 is that your sum variable starts at 1. You should instead set sum to the first number that is entered (starting at 1 breaks addition; starting at 0 breaks multiplication), and fix the undefined behaviour that @AdrianMole mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The program is invalid and has undefined behavior.

For starters variable length arrays is not a standard C+ feature

```
int p = 1, y = 0;
double sum = 1;
int many[p];
```

And in any case you defined an array with one element. So the only valid index to access elements of the array is 0.

Even in the first statement that uses the array

```
cin >> many[p];
```

it is accessed outside its bounds.

You should use the standard class template `std::vector`. Or as in fact you are dealing with one value then there is even no sense to use a container, Define a scalar object instead of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of the sum is 1, that's why it is adding 1 more. We can't keep it 0 either, because then it will mess up the '*' and '/' cases. 
I have added the initial sum value for all the cases.
Also, I would suggest you, to use switch cases instead of if, else statements.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main() {

double x;
int p = 1, y = 0;
double sum = 1;
int many[p];
char op;

cout << "How many numbers are you working with today?" << endl;
cin >> x;

do
{
    if (y > x)
    break;

cout << "Enter number " << y + 1 << ":" << endl;
cin >> many[p];

cout << "What would you like the numbers to do: (+ - / *)" << endl;
cin >> op;

if (op == '+')
{
if (y == 0) {
  sum = 0;
}
sum+=many[p];
cout << sum <<endl;
}

else if (op == '-')
{
  if (y == 0) {
    sum = 0;
  }
  sum-=many[p];
  cout << sum <<endl;
}

else if (op == '*')
{
  if (y == 0) {
    sum = 1;
  }
  sum*=many[p];
  cout << sum <<endl;
}

else if (op == '/')
{
  if (y == 0) {
    sum = 1;
  }
  sum/=many[p];
  cout << sum <<endl;
}

else {cout << "ERROR: Enter correct value." << endl;}

    y++;

}

    while (y < x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things here that don't make sense.

- You are starting with sum = 1. this is why the value is always +1
- `many` is an array of size 1, can be changed to single int.
- you are accessing `many[p]` which is `many[1]` which is out of bounds. you can only access `many[0]`

the rest I leave it to you to find,